# Only text links on navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I have looked at other similar questions but I couldn't get it to apply to mine. I want the boxes surrounding each text link to be clickable instead of just the text.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-home">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-games"> 
            <a href="games.html">Games</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-chat">
            <a href="chat.html">Chat</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-suggestions">
            <a href="suggestions.html">Suggestions</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
width: 900;
clear: right;
height: 55px;
margin-left: 22px;
margin-right: 22px;
padding: 0;
z-index: 5;
overflow: visible;
background: #161616; 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #161616 0%, #282828 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#161616), color-stop(100%,#282828)); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #161616 0%,#282828 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #161616 0%,#282828 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #161616 0%,#282828 100%); 
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #161616 0%,#282828 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#161616', endColorstr='#282828',GradientType=0 );
border: 1px solid #090909;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.nav li {
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0px 89px;
width: 55;
text-align: center;
height: 55px;
border-right: 1px solid #090909;
box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.1);
-webkit-transition:all 0.2s linear; 
-moz-transition:all 0.2inear; 
-o-transition:all 1s linear; 
transition:all 0.2s linear; 
}

.nav li.logo:hover { opacity: 1; background-color: transparent;}

.nav li:last-child { border: none; box-shadow: none; }
```

I added `display: block;` here which made above and below the text clickable but not to the left or right.

```
.nav li a, nav ul li a:visited {
line-height: 55px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
color: #9c9c9c;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: "Droid Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
-webkit-transition:all 0.2s linear; 
-moz-transition:all 0.2s linear; 
-o-transition:all 0.2s linear; 
transition:all 0.2s linear;     
}

.nav li:hover { 
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
background-color: #191919\9; 
-webkit-transition:all 0.2s linear; 
-moz-transition:all 0.2s linear; 
-o-transition:all 0.2s linear; 
transition:all 0.2s linear;
color: white;
}
.nav li:hover a { color: white; 
-webkit-transition:all 0.2s linear; 
-moz-transition:all 0.2s linear; 
-o-transition:all 0.2s linear; 
transition:all 0.2s linear;
}

#nav-home .nav li.nav-home a, #nav-games .nav li.nav-games a, #nav-chat .nav li.nav-chat a, 
#nav-comments .nav li.nav-comments a  { color: white; }
```

Heres the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U2d9X/3/ for a visual. If you could help it would be greatly appreciated. If any more information or clarification is needed please ask instead of rejecting this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Remove the left/right padding from your LI elements.

2) Adjust the width of your LI elements.

3)  `a { width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important; }`

Comment: Or just simply add the padding removed from `li` to `a` http://jsfiddle.net/U2d9X/6/

Comment: @Morpheus if you add padding to the link elements, then they will all be different sizes. Not sure if this is what the OP wants.

Comment: OP wants them to be clickable :)

Comment: Thanks I got it to work somewhat but i'll have more time later to fix it now that ik how.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<li>` tags inside the `<a>` tags. For example:

```
<a href="index.html">
    <li class="nav-home">
        Home
    </li>
</a>
```

Then, in the CSS, change `.nav li a, nav ul li a:visited` to `.nav a, nav ul a:visited`, since `<a>` is no longer in `<li>`.

On the jsFiddle, I made the HTML change to the "Home" tab only so that you can compare it with the other tags.

[Altered code](http://jsfiddle.net/U2d9X/3/)

Answer (score -1):

If all the buttons are the same dimension, you can always assign a size to the link element itself, such as:

a {

width: 100%;
height: 100%;

}

Just tweak it until things match up nicely.